# Not able to export Highchart.js after Drill Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, export, drilldown

I have a **Bar chart**, that each Bar drill down to a **Line Chart**, in the Bar Chart it shows me the **Export button** so I can print, pdf, etc.

But when I'm in the **Line Chart** it only shows me the **Back button**, not the Export button.

Here is the Bar Chart, allowing me to export it.
[image]

But when I Drill Down for example 2016 Bar, It doesn't allow me to export it because it only shows me the Back Button, not the export button.
[image]

Is it possible to get **both buttons**, Back Button and Export Button on Drill Down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the `drillUpButton` covers `contextButton`. The solution is to change position of one of them.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown.drillUpButton
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5rxhjt9v/

Comment: Thanks, never noticed that were in the same position.